# How would I traverse a 2D array by finding the local maxima by checking if all the numbers around it are smaller than it?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

How would I traverse a 2D array by finding the local maxima by checking if all the numbers around it are smaller than it? I am really confused on how I would do this in code. I need to get the position and I only need local maximums, not absolute maximums.

```
void reportMaxima(int rows, int cols, int grid[ rows ][ cols ])
{

}
```

Comment: You need to get the position, or only the value of the maximum?

Comment: Also, do you need all local maxima, or only the absolute maximum? (By the question, it seems you need all the local maxima and their position, right?)

Comment: You will need another array (should be `bool arr_out[rows][cols]`) in which you will put a `true` if that point is a maxima, and a `false` if it is not.

Comment: I need to get the position and I only need local maximums, not absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void report_maxima(int rows, int cols, int arr_in[rows][cols],
                    bool arr_out[rows][cols])
{
    int i, j;
    int k, l;

    memset(arr_out, 0, rows * cols * sizeof(arr_out[0][0]));
//  memset(arr_out, 0, sizeof(arr_out));  I think this doesn't work :(

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            for (k = i - 1; k <= (i + 1); k++) {
                if (k < 0)
                    continue;
                if (k >= rows)
                    break;

                for (l = j - 1; l <= (j + 1); l++) {
                    if (l < 0)
                        continue;
                    if (l >= cols)
                        break;

                    if (arr_in[i][j] < arr_in[k][l])
                        goto not_maxima;
                }
            }

            arr_out[i][j]   = true;
            continue;

not_maxima:
        }
    }
}
```

First you need a `bool` array where to store the output info: whether a point is a maxima (`true`) or not (`false`).

You need to initialize that array to `0` (`false`) before storing the points where it is `true`. The best way to do that is by using `memset()`.

Then, you need obviously to iterate over the input array. (`i` and `j` do that)

For each point of the input array, you check all the neighbours. (`k` and `l` do that).
You need to be sure that the neighbour you are trying to access is inside the array bounds (the `if - continue` and `if - break` do that).

Then, you check if all those neighbours are smaller than the point you are on.  The first neighbour you find that is greater than your point tells you that you are not in a local maxima, and you should skip to the next point.  If after checking all the neighboours you haven't found any neighbour greater than your point, then you are in a local maxima. **(or at least in an inflection point)**.

That last thing is important:  If you want to be sure, you should add a lot of checking, which would slow down the algorithm a lot. It depends on your needs.

**EDIT:**

Fixed a bug when using incorrect input to `sizeof()`.

Comment: Mark it as an answer if it is the answer to your question, please.

Comment: Marked as correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get the memset function?

Comment: `string.h` It is a standard C function.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run throw all of the cells in the array using 2 for loops

```
 int i,j;
 for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)   {
  for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)   {
   if(check(i,j,rows,cols,grid))   {
    //do something.
   }
   else  {
    //do something else.
   }
  }
 }
```

Then in code you can check all of the numbers around it. The key for this task is to not be lazy, just check every cell around it. Make sure that you don't try to access memory that is not part of the array.

[i-1][j-1] , [i-1][j] , [i-1][j+1]

[i][j-1]   , the cell , [i][j+1]

[i+1][j-1] , [i+1][j] , [i+1][j+1]

So you will need to verify that the +1's are smaller then rows and cols (respectively) and that the -1's are bigger-equal to 0. After that check if the cell in question is **smaller** then the specific cell next to it, If so return false. At the end of the functions, if no near cell is bigger return true.

```
bool check(int i, int j, int rows, int cols,int grid[rows][cols]) {
 if((i - 1 >= 0) && (j - 1 >= 0) && (grid[i-1][j-1]) > (grid[i][j]))
  return false;
 if((i - 1 >= 0) && (grid[i-1][j] > grid[i][j]))
  return false; 
 //etc...
 return true;
}
```

There are more esthetic ways to do it, but when you begin to code readability should be the most important thing. If you use a helper function remember to declare it before using it, Good luck!

Comment: You should explicitly enclose each comparison in that long `if`s between parentheses

Comment: Also, consider using loops, if you care about readability.

Comment: Also, and I think it is the most important thing, please indent your code correctly.

Comment: You missed the types of the arguments of your helper function

Comment: @Cacahuete , I accept 3 of your comments, but I do think that my code is more readable since it plainly state what it dose. This is why I felt the need to post it, because loops are not readable for noobs.

Comment: Repeatition isn't a good thing. People new to C should see how things are done correctly. If they need an explanation of how loops work, they should google it, or look for it here. When you understand how loops work, it is very easy to follow these two inner loops. Also the reduced number of lines of code helps to follow the structure. If you put a long line for each neighbour, you have to carefully stop at each line to see what it does, and why it is different than the others. Also, if you do a mistake, good luck finding it.

Comment: Maybe a helper function could help readability.  That's something I've thought about it; I've used this function before and almost did that once, but I think that the helper function would be almost as big as the original one, so I decided not to, but that's debatable.  There would be a gain in the main function, which would be a lot shorter.

Comment: @Cacahuete I guess readability is just not well defined, same as the correct way to educate. The helper function was actually more in service of the post then the code tbh. Good talk, have an up vote ;)

Comment: You can NOT put an argument that is an array before the variables that determine its size.  That will not compile.  The values `rows` and `cols` do not exist at that time.

Comment: The parentheses you added are wrong. Check

Comment: @Cacahuete you got me good on this post.

Comment: @Cacahuete I was to annoyed to say thank you, but thank you.